# How to get alert from a diff output using python

Tags: python, diff

I am writing a python script to monitor changes in webpage. I have the diff command implemented in python and I have the diff output files in a folder.

I have 260 diff output files. Logically i cannot check all 260 to know which file has changes.

Is there a python solution to read all the diff files and alert me with the filenames which have the changes.

```
sample filename in my diff output folder: ['4streaming', 'net-log-2016-09- 26-12:29:32']-diff-output-2016-09-27-13:07:32.html



Required output: 4streaming has changed
```

Forgive me if my way of asking question is wrong. I am new to stackoverflow forum wrt asking questions.

Answer (score 4):

To check if two files have the same content you can use the [filecmp](https://docs.python.org/2/library/filecmp.html) module:

```
>>> import filecmp
>>> filecmp.cmp('a_file.txt', 'another_file.txt')
True
```

So in your case where you have a lot of files, you could store their names on a list (ex.File_list), and using `itertools` compare each item==file on the list only once with the others:

```
import itertools
for i,j in itertools.combinations(File_list, 2):
    filecmp.cmp(i, j)   #where i,j are actual file names
    # do something based on the result
```

*To get a list with all the file names in a directory take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-to-list-all-files-of-a-directory-in-python) post.

Another way would be by hashing them and comparing the hashes.